# Insert a string starting at a given index

Tags: string, haskell, ghci

I am completely new to Haskell. I need to insert a given string at a given index of a string that may already be non-empty.

This is what I have so far. However, after seemingly running with no errors, when I ask what the value of `t` is ghci just hangs indefinitely.

Haskell:

`create = ("",0,0,"","")`

```
addText (m,l,p,_,k) i = 
    let a = take p m
        m = drop p m
        full = a++i++m
    in (full, length full, p + length i, "", k)
```

Where `m` is the text to add to, `l` is the length of `m` and `p` is the index to start adding the new string at

Output:

```
*Main> t = create
```

`*Main> t`

`("",0,0,"","")`

`*Main> t = addText t "test"`

`*Main> t`

`(hangs)`

Comment: That's because you write `t = addText t "test"`. As a result you thus define `t` in terms of itself. Note that in Haskell you do not *assign* to variables, you declare them. If you write `r = addText t "test"` it will work. But the same holds for `m` in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let m = drop p m
```

is a circular definition. It doesn't mean "set `m` to be smaller than what `m` was before", because remember, it is impossible to modify variables in Haskell. Instead, you ignore the existing `m`, and define a new variable named `m`, defined in terms of itself: an evaluation which can never be completed. This may seem like a silly feature, but in other situations it is in fact quite useful to define values in terms of themselves, which is why the language allows it.

You then make the same mistake again, with

```
t = addText t "test"
```

defining `t` in terms of itself.

You can fix both of these errors by using uniquely named variables, e.g.

```
r = addText t "test"
```

at which point you will run into exciting new errors: `create`'s inferred type signature does not match the inferred type signature for `addText`, because of type defaulting rules. If you specify explicit type signatures, or inline the definition of `create`, you will finally get what you wanted:

```
*Main> addText ("",0,0,"","") "test"
("test",4,4,"","")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like many people new to Haskell, you write functions in an *imperative* style where you *update* variables.

A variable in Haskell however can not be updated: you do not *(re)assign* a value to a variable, you declare a variable. In case you write `i = i + 1`, you do *not* take the old value of `i`, and add `1` to it, you here declare `i` in terms of itself, so `i = i + 1`, means that we have written an infinite deep recursive expression `i = ( ( (...) + 1) + 1) + 1`.

In your function you seem to update `m`:

```
addText (m, l, p, _, k) i = 
    let a = take p m
        m = drop p m
        full = a++i++m
    in (full, length full, p + length i, "", k)
```

So you have written `m` in terms of itself, and although due to lazyness this will not *per se* loop, in case the value of `m` is necessary, we will get stuck into infinite recursion.

By using a new variable, we can solve the problem:

```
addText (m, l, p, _, k) i = 
    let a = take p m
        z = drop p m
        full = a++i++z
    in (full, length full, p + length i, "", k)
```

The same phenomena occurs if you write:

```
Prelude> t = addText t "test"
```

you again define `t` in terms of itself. You thus better use another variable or constants:

```
Prelude> t = addText ("",0,0,"","") "test"
```

Comment: You can use `splitAt` to obtain `a` and `z` in one go